# How to validate String in Java by matches?

Tags: java, regex, string

To validate `String` in Java I can use `String.matches()`. I would like to validate a simple string `"*.txt"` where `"*"` means anything. Input e.g. `test.txt` is correct, but `test.tt` is not correct, because of `".tt"`. I tried to use `matches("[*].txt")`, but it doesn't work. How can I improve this matches? Thanks.

Comment: Use `".*\\.txt"`. The `.*` means any characters, even none, so if you want a class of characters, you would have to put that between brackets, like so: `[A-Za-z0-9_]*`. Replace `*` with `+` if you want at least one character.

Answer (score 2):

**Do not use code, you don't understand!**

For your simple problem you could totally avoid using a regular expression and just use

```
yourString.endsWith(".txt")
```

and if you want to perform this comparison case insensitive (i.e. allow ".TXT" or ".tXt") use

```
yourString.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt")
```

If you want to learn more about regular expressions in java, I'd recomment a tutorial. For example [this one](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html).

Answer (score 1):

You may try this for `txt` files:

```
"file.txt".matches("^.*[.]txt$")
```

Basically `^` means the start of your string. `.*` means match anything greedy, hence as much as you can get to make the expression match. And `[.]` means match the dot character. The suffix `txt` is just the txt text itself. And finally `$` is the anchor for the end of the string, which ensures that the string does not contain anything more.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.+`, it means any character having one or unlimited lengths. It will ensure to avoid the inputs like only `.txt`

```
matches(".+[.]txt")
```

FYI: `[.]` simply matches with the dot character.

Comment: Is there an advantage to using `[.]` compared to `\\.`?

Comment: :D Just didn't want to use `\\ ` its horrible in Java.

Comment: I agree, it is ugly. I was just wondering if there was an advantage other than readability.

Comment: No other advantages, both are same so far I know.